# How to send a request without 'Host Header' using Python?

Tags: python, html, http, urllib2, urllib

I have been trying for many days now, so here I am finally asking, may be dumb question for most of the experts.
I am using PyUnit for API testing of my application. 
The application (to be tested) is deployed on one of the local servers over here. The application prevents hackers from doing malicious activities. So I am accessing any website (protected by this application) through this application. e.g. `http://my-security-app/stackoverflow/login`  ,  `http://my-security-app/website-to-be-protected` etc.

Almost the whole framework is running around Urllib and Urllib2.

Scenario:- I need to send a request without 'Host' header or a request with 'Host123' as a header name instead of original, using python.

I have been trying below mentioned code. But its not working for me.

*"Test failed because of an exception: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor"*

```
    host = "12.1.3.16"
    with closing(socket.create_connection((host, 80))) as s:
     # send request without Host header
        s.sendall(b"GET /mywebsite/administrator/ HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
        #"Host12:{}\r\n".format(host).encode('ascii', 'strict') +
        b"Connection: close\r\n\r\n")
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By definition response is sent by the server. If it is sent *to* the server then it is a request. If a server sends requests then it plays a role of a client for the exchange. Anyway, you could define a mock server for testing that sends preconfigured responses that contain whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for a quick response. Even I was confused with the term "response" because as per my understanding, we can't manipulate the response coming from the server, using python.
Now coming to our problem. Suppose I want to check if I can send duplicate headers in a request to the server. Could you provide any help regarding that?

Comment: you need to be more specific aka provide a [*minimal* code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that sends a header and show your attempt to duplicate the header.

Comment: I got it Sebastian, I sent out some data (request) so that I can get some specific headers twice in response. Thanks btw for your co-operation. I have one more challenge now. In the same scenario I need to replace 'Host' in the request with 'Host123' before sending out the request. Any clues?

Comment: you could use `socket` directly to send invalid http request. Here's [code example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22371785/4279)

Comment: Sebastian, I saw the example code you mentioned, you are sending "Host" in your request. If I need to send "Host123" in my request to the server, where I need to make change exactly. Could you please elaborate this "   s.sendall(b"GET /q/22371297/4279 HTTP/1.x\r\n" +
              "Host: {}\r\n".format(host).encode('ascii', 'strict') +
              b"Connection: close\r\n\r\n") "

Comment: If it is not obvious; learn [http basics](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/http_basics.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link, however, I think you didn't get my question Sebastian. The solution you have shown is for webhosts. I am doing API testing and the server is deployed on local server in one of the VMs over here. And I am accessing the application(to be tested) through this local host. for example- http://local-server/product-to-be-tested and host  = local-server (not like stackoverflow.com)
So in this case .format(host) and Host: will not take the values. 
Could you help me on this?

Comment: yes, I do not understand it because it is not mentioned in your question. [Update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22375673/edit), do not put the relevant info in comments. If it is localhost then the header is `Host: localhost:<port>` (replace `<port>` by the actual port number). If the server is *in the same process* then create the request using API specific to the server e.g., `app.test_client()` if your server written using `flask` framework

Comment: I don't know where you are heading to exactly. I have updated my question, making it ultra specific ;). Let me know if you could explain more clearly.
Note: I am aware of urllib,urllib2,http basics if not at expert level.

Comment: I am able to send a request with invalid HTTP protocol, request without HTTP protocol. But I am not able to send my request without HOST header with valid HTTP version. (i.e. HTTP/1.1)

Answer (score 1):

Use [httpbin](https://github.com/kennethreitz/httpbin) test server for this. It is written in Python, btw.

Description:

> Testing an HTTP Library can become difficult sometimes. PostBin.org is
>   fantastic for testing POST requests, but not much else. This exists to
>   cover all kinds of HTTP scenarios. Additional endpoints are being
>   considered (e.g. /deflate).
>
> All endpoint responses are JSON-encoded.

Author provides even public service based on this server at http://httpbin.org