# How to rename the 'Host : stackoverflow.com' to 'Host123: stackoverflow.com' in http request using Python?

Tags: python, html, http, urllib2, urllib

I have one strange requirement. I need to rename the host header in my request using python and rest api. e.g. if the normal request goes with "Host: stackoverflow.com", after the modification it should go like "Host123: stackoverflow.com".

Please use simplest language as I am not very good in Python or HTML :)

Comment: [How to send a request without 'Host Header' using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22375673/4279)

Comment: Well! that doesn't allow me to edit the header name. 400-Bad Request!!
The solution you are suggesting only allows me to change the host value. i.e. Host = "myvalue". This is not I actually want. I need Host123 = "stackoverflow.com". I am not very much sure but I think we need use httplib here, because there I saw that we are setting "Host" as a header name. But how to do that is a challenge

Comment: yes, sending incorrect request (no `Host` header) must lead to 400 http error from HTTP/1.1 server. HTTP/1.1 protocol *requires* `Host` header. You could try `HTTP/1.0` to send request without `Host` header.

Comment: HTTP/1.0 leads to "505-Unknown HTTP version". Requirement is I need to send my request with Host Header name renamed from Host to Host123. (with valid HTTP version that is : HTTP/1.1)

Comment: http/1.1 server *must* return 400 http code for a request without `Host` header.